# electron - how to generate file checksum

Tags: node.js, vue.js, electron

I have an electron app that will generate encrypted files. I want to provide to the user the checksum of the encrypted files to give the user the ability to check if the files aren't modified. How I can achive this with electron and node js api?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Node.js has the inbuilt [crypto](https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html) library with a variety of different crypto algorothims

```js
const crypto = require('crypto');
function getChecksum(path) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      // if absolutely necessary, use md5
      const hash = crypto.createHash('sha256');
      const input = fs.createReadStream(path);
      input.on('error', reject);
      input.on('data', (chunk) => {
          hash.update(chunk);
      });
      input.on('close', () => {
          resolve(hash.digest('hex'));
      });
    });
}
```

Example usage:

```js
getChecksum('someFile.txt')
.then(checksum => console.log(`checksum is ${checksum}`))
.catch(err => console.log(err));
```

Comment: nice solution. At the moment I'm using crypto to generate randomBytes for filenames. I can use `ipcRenderer` and then `ipcMain` and your suggestetd solution to create the checksum right? If I need to verify it I can use the same function?

Comment: Ok, I was thinking that another function were needed to verify the checksum. I will compare it with an internal database of the app that hold the last 10 encrypted files checksum. thank you for the help

Answer (score 0):

If the file `contents` are already in memory:

```js
const checksum = crypto.createHash('sha256').update(contents).digest('base64')
```